# Java error java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

Tags: java

I have a java class file with the following section :

```
 private static String getBusinessObjectList(String paramString)
  {
    String str1 = "";
    HashSet localHashSet = new HashSet();
    ZipFile localZipFile = null;
    try
    {
      localZipFile = new ZipFile(paramString);
      Enumeration localEnumeration = localZipFile.entries();
      while (localEnumeration.hasMoreElements())
      {
        Object localObject1 = (ZipEntry)localEnumeration.nextElement();
        String str2 = ((ZipEntry)localObject1).getName();
        String[] arrayOfString = str2.split("/");
        if ((arrayOfString != null) && (arrayOfString.length == 2)) {
          localHashSet.add(arrayOfString[0]);
        }
      }
      if (localZipFile != null) {
        try
        {
          localZipFile.close();
        }
        catch (IOException localIOException4)
        {
          localIOException4.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      localIterator = localHashSet.iterator();
    }
    catch (IOException localIOException2)
    {
      localIOException2.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
      if (localZipFile != null) {
        try
        {
          localZipFile.close();
        }
        catch (IOException localIOException4)
        {
          localIOException4.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
    Iterator localIterator;
    while (localIterator.hasNext())
    {
      Object localObject1 = localIterator.next();
      if (str1.length() > 0) {
        str1 = str1 + ",";
      }
      str1 = str1 + String.valueOf(localObject1);
    }
    return str1;
  }
}
```

This section is erroring out with :

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:115)
        at xcm.oracle.apps.fusion.GenericToolUpload.getBusinessObjectList(GenericToolUpload.java:277)
        at xcm.oracle.apps.fusion.GenericToolUpload.main(GenericToolUpload.java:82)
```

The file it is picking is encrypted. But this program should pick it
Can anyone help me out of what this error can be ?

Comment: Why do you think that this should be able to open an encrypted zip file?

Comment: By which mechanism is it encrypted ?

Comment: @davidxxx- PGP encryption. So when i open this file in my desktop also it will show as invalid as it is encrypted